# Предлог об ошибке и об стену (моей головой)...

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, сколько значений имеет обычный предлог "о". Всегда ли перед гласными, пишется как "об" (если можно, обычным и "непространственным" языком)?

Answer (score 1):

"Сколько значений" я Вам не отвечу. Это - смотря как считать. Основные - одно или два:
~1. Используется с предложным падежом для указания объекта. Обычно - обсуждения, размышления.  *Говорить о чем-то, думать о ком-то*.   
~2. Используется с винительным падежом для указания объекта возвратного действия: *порезаться о стекло, разбиться о стену, тереться о ковер*, реже - прямого с пассивной ролью объекта : *испачкать пальто о покрашенный забор*.
Остальные - малоактуальные ("жить бок о бок") или устаревающие ("дракон о трёх головах")

Еще "О" может быть частицей или междометием, это тоже опускаю.

Насчет формы. Если опустить некоторые подробности, то дело обстоит так.
Предлоги **о/об/обо** - эквивалентны, точнее это разные формы одного предлога. Перед гласными **А, И, О, У, Э** (и **Ы** - в именах собственных) - всегда **об**. В остальных случаях - почти всегда **О**, хотя в некоторых случаях наряду с ним возможно и **об**: об стену. **Обо** употребляется в некоторых фиксированных случаях только с винительным падежом ("обо что?"), рассказать о них кратко и доходчиво не берусь, у Аванесова это полстраницы убористого конспективного текста.

Я Вас как-то спрашивал, у Вас русский - родной? Вы, вроде, не ответили...